# Populate JavaScript Array With Required Form Fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbytagname

Is there a way to populate a JavaScript array with form fields that have the `required` attribute?

I tried this bit of code...

```
var requiredfields = new Array();

function getInputs() {
    var fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        alert('I am input field ' + i);
        //var required = fields[i].getAttribute('required');
        if (fields[i].getAttribute('required')) {
            fields[i].style.border = '1px solid #ff0000';
            requiredfields.push(fields[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not even putting the border or showing the alerts.  I'm not really even sure if `getElementsByTagName` is returning the data, correctly.

It's probable that my code is wack.  Hehehe...

Comment: The border was only for testing purposes.  I can't use CSS to populate a JavaScript array (remember the question?).

Comment: For the love...I just realized that one reason why I wasn't getting the alerts and stuff was because my function was being called before the elements were rendered.  I put the function call at the end of the page and it worked better.  Positioning is always worth remembering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script:

http://jsfiddle.net/2u3kZ/

```
var requiredfields = new Array();

var fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (fields[i].getAttribute("required") != null) {
        fields[i].style.border = '1px solid #ff0000';
        requiredfields.push(fields[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `!= null` part.  I wasn't sure how to address `required` since it wasn't `required = "required"` (Boolean attribute).

Comment: One thing that this doesn't account for is if a field is marked as `required` but also `disabled`.  A form will disregard `required`, but this JavaScript still marks it as such.  More logic could be included, but what I did was remove `required` for any fields that might get disabled and simply add `required` with JavaScript when they get enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers you can do this:

```
var required = document.querySelectorAll('input[required]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(required, function(element){
  element.style.border = '1px solid #ff0000';
});
```

Or just use a CSS rule in your stylesheet:

```
input[required] {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Would iOS's version of Safari be included in "modern browsers"?  The reason I'm having to do this is because it ignores `required` and `type="email"` (or more specifically, the format of said field).  Also, remember the question is about populating an array (not adding CSS borders).

Comment: What iOS version? `required` contains all your required fields in a pseudo-array that you can loop. If you want real array just do `[].slice.call(required)`.

Comment: I haven't worked with `Array.prototype` before.  I'll have to study up on that, a little.

Comment: I checked a basic HTML5 form (using `required` and `type="email"`) on an iPad with iOS 6.something and it allowed me to submit a completely empty form.  [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) also notes that there is no form validation in iOS Safari.